# Apache Nifi: Counting numbers in a string inside a csv file

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, data-processing

I have a csv which contains two columns. But the columns `download` and `upload` have a string that can have multiple number of values separated by commas.

```
download,upload
"12,3,43","2,33,7,10"
"2,1","4,5,6,23,1"
```

I need to add each value inside the string and form a new csv with the addition.So after the Nifi Workflow my output csv must be:

```
download,upload
57,52
3,39
```

Basically should be the addition of the values inside each string as shown below. Hope you can suggest me the processors to be used and the configurations to be changed in order to achieve this output csv from the input csv as shown below.

Comment: ExecuteScript processor

Comment: @daggett This seems like a possible route. But I am not supposed to use code in my project. Is there any other processor or a group of processors which can make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [**JoltTransformJSON**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) processor, which transforms JSON. It offers a `split` and `sum` transformation, which you need to get you desired output.

The strategy is:

- Inspect each line of the CSV file
- Convert from CSV to JSON
- Apply a Jolt transformation, that splits, converts the string to an integer and finally sums
- Convert the record back to CSV
- Merge record into a CSV file

Overall flow:

[image]

GenerateFlowFile:

[image]

SplitRecord will take each CSV line and transform it to JSON:

[image]

Create a `CSVReader` and `JsonRecordSetWriter`. Setup CSVReader to use first line as header line. Leave the default properties. Set records per split to 1.

Use a `JoltTransformJson` processor and provide following jolt specification:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "downloadSplit": "=split(',', @(2,download))",
      "uploadSplit": "=split(',', @(2,upload))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "downloadSplit": ["=toInteger", 0],
      "uploadSplit": ["=toInteger", 0]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "download": "=intSum(@(1,downloadSplit))",
      "upload": "=intSum(@(1,uploadSplit))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "download": "download",
      "upload": "upload"
    }
  }
]
```

1. Split
2. Convert to integer
3. Sum
4. Overwrite original download/uploaded with transformed ones

Convert record back to CSV:

[image]

Leave the default properties of reader and writer. Finally merge each single record back into a CSV file:

[image]

Use CSV reader and writer with default properties. You can control the number of records per CSV file by adjusting the properties of `MergeRecord`. Read more about the meaning of the properties [**here**](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Nifi-Merge-Content/td-p/158619?lightbox-message-images-158620=20816i090C616A3B3D89F4).

Output:

[image]

Notice that the order of the original lines changed. First line corresponds to the last line in the input.

Comment: Record per split is not defined in SplitRecord processor and is mandatory.

Comment: @HimsaraGallege set it to 1

Comment: There is an error by the "SplitRecord" Processor saying "Failed to parse incoming data."

Comment: @HimsaraGallege your CSVReader configuration is missing something. Ensure that it is set it to infer schema and treat first line as header line.

Comment: Everything is set accordingly in the CSVReader configurations. Is it possible for you to share your xml...

Comment: @HimsaraGallege https://gist.github.com/artjomzab/0780c8f459b0b4cdbc2a761a569a7482